# React-Table: Specify optional column (depending on result set availability)

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

In React-Table I'm building out my table columns using `useMemo` as below,

```
// React-Table Columns
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
        {
            Header: "requesterEmail",
            accessor: "requesterEmail",
            isVisible: true
        },
        {
            Header: "Date Submitted",
            accessor: "actionDate",
            isVisible: true
        },
  ...
```

The table is shared by multiple components, and some components may pass in a resultset containing additional columns. If available, I'd like to include those columns. I'd like to do something like

```
        /* The Frequency only applies in some cases, e.g. depending on prop, 
            or availability of accessor */ 
        {props.someprop === 'special' &&
            {
                Header: "Special Column",
                accessor: "specialColumn",
                isVisible: true             
            }
        },
```

or

```
/* Check availability of accessor? */ 
{specialColumn &&
    {
        Header: "Special Column",
        accessor: "specialColumn",
        isVisible: true             
    }
},
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.You can do this by add `props.someprop` in the dependencies of useMemo.

```
const columns = React.useMemo(() => {
  const result = [
    {
      Header: "requesterEmail",
      accessor: "requesterEmail",
      isVisible: true,
    },
    {
      Header: "Date Submitted",
      accessor: "actionDate",
      isVisible: true,
    },
    ...
  ];
  if (props.someprop === "special") {
    result.push({
      Header: "Special Column",
      accessor: "specialColumn",
      isVisible: true,
    });
  }

  return result;
}, [preDependencies, props.someprop]);
```

Comment: Is the final `}, [..., props.someprop]);` the actual syntax, with `...`? Or should it just be `}, [props.someprop]` in my case?

Comment: It depends on your current dependencies. If it is empty, you just change to `[props.someprop]`

Comment: I had to change it to `[props.someprop]` because it was giving the error `props is not iterable`. Otherwise it's working, thanks